# Authenticating Against Multiple Okta Tenancies

Tags: okta

I have an Angular CLI app and a ASP.NET Web API back-end.  I've secured both against a private Okta tenancy (group of users) using OpenId Connect.

What I need to do now is extend the application so that it also authenticates against the company tenancy.  The company tenancy is limited by domain, so all of it's users are "someone@mycompany.com" etc.  Whereas the private tenancy can have users with any domain in their username.

Does anyone know if Okta have a product where I can authenticate against multiple sources, as though it's a single source?  Or is there another recommended way?  Sorry for the open/wide question, but I'm out of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Okta does not have any program that recognizes the IDPs for you yet. There might be something underway. However, there is a way to achieve this.

1. Add any [IDP to Okta](https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/saml-login/). This will give you and IDP Id. When the user enters their credentials. Figure out what IDP they are using and add that id when requesting a token
2. Ask the user for their credentials AND their IDP and map that to appropriate call to get the token.

To get a token from Okta this is the call: 
`{{url}}/oauth2/v1/authorize?client_id={{client_id}}&response_type=id_token&scope=openid groups email profile&redirect_uri={{redirect_url}}&state=state&nonce=nonce`

If I need to used IDP I just need to add IDP id:

`{{url}}/oauth2/v1/authorize?client_id={{client_id}}&idp={{idp_id}}&response_type=id_token&scope=openid groups email profile&redirect_uri={{redirect_url}}&state=state&nonce=nonce`